# Flex AdvancedDatagrid editable but not allowed to change data

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4

I have an advanced datagrid, but I want users to allow to copy some lines they want. when I use the property `editable` they are allowed to select the text they need, but they also are allowed to edit this. How can I prevent that?

I want users to be able to select any text in the datagrid, but they are not allowed to change the value of the grid. They should only be allowed to select and copy (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solitions is:

1. Create `SelectableItemRenderer` that extends `AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer`. In class constructor write:

   ```
   public function SelectableItemRenderer()
   {
       super();

       selectable = true;
   }
   ```
2. Set `SelectableItemRenderer` as grid item renderer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I've put an text input component in the item editor of the advancedDataGridColumn and that worked!
Just set the advancedDatagrid editable true and on the textinput editable false!